# App rejected in the Review from the Appstore-- Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ionic3, in-app-purchase

Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase

Your app unlocks or enables additional functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store, which is not appropriate for the App Store.

We noticed that your app contains a payment mechanism other than in-app purchase for digital content or to unlock features or functionality within your app, which is not appropriate for the App Store. In-app purchase is the only valid in-app payment mechanism for digital content.

Note: Continuing to hide functionality within your app or other dishonest acts may result in the removal of your apps from the App Store and termination of your Apple Developer Program membership and all associated memberships.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please remove all external or third-party payment mechanisms and implement in-app purchase to facilitate digital good transactions, including unlocking features or functionality within your app.

If you believe your use of an alternative payment mechanism is a permissible use case, please respond directly to this message in Resolution Center with detailed information.

Comment: Please add some more text to the question. I assume that this is the error you get when submitting an app. what do you need help with?

Comment: It seems like in your app you are selling additional features through third-party payment mechanisms and not using In App purchase for that flow.

Comment: When adding purchases in an app, if they are digital (content/no ads/functionality) you MUST use apple in-app purchase. If you are selling physical items, that need to be delivered to a person, then you can use outside purchasing

Comment: @JoSSte -- We noticed that your app contains a payment mechanism other than in-app purchase for digital content or to unlock features or functionality within your app, which is not appropriate for the App Store. In-app purchase is the only valid in-app payment mechanism for digital content.

Note: Continuing to hide functionality within your app or other dishonest acts may result in the removal of your apps from the App Store and termination of your Apple Developer Program membership and all associated memberships.

Answer (score 1):

@sujeet,

First of all, you have not mentioned what type of product you are selling to users? If you are selling digital content i.e. any kind of plan, activation, You must have to use In-App Purchase.

Apple is providing 4 types of In-App Purchases, choose your best on from that and create a In-App Purchase Items in iTunes Connect.

Apple will not allow any kind of third-party payment system in any apps which sells degital content from app.